# calculate based on the Quantity

Tags: price

I´m new in magento, But i like a lot.
I´m trying to figer out to calculate a price based on:
Product price, Quantity, number of inks.

And based on number of inks, it needs stencil price.
1 ink = 350
2 ink = 700

I hope someone can figure this out.
I Think i have try every e-store there is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

actually this one is easy.
once you create the listing and are inside the admin part, on the left there will be Prices tab, click on that, then click on tiered pricing and add as many as you like, you can filter it for qty and by users in that field.

Comment: Hello

Thanks for answer me, nobody have make this script to work.
I´m wondering if you coude give me an example how to do.

Nobody have make this script to work.....

Comment: I think OP is asking as well on how to get the Number of Inks (a Custom Option I guess) working with the Tier Price.